# "print" and "range" work different (or not at all) in different Python shells in Windows?

Tags: python

Recently I have started learning python on windows.  I am puzzled because the way it shows me output inside VS tools for python and in Iron Python Console.  And similar difference in PyScripter and IronPython.

The print command works differently in IronPython console and in Python 3.2 Interactive within Visual Studio.

```
print("Hello") # works perfectly inside visual studio 
Hello
print "Hello"  # gives error when running ctrl+F5 
Invalid Syntax
print "Hello"  # works great inside IronPython console
Hello
```

Another I thing I noticed that in PyScripter for windows the following code produces nothing

```
range(6)
#nothing happens in PyScripter
range(6) #inside IronPython console works fine
[0,1,2,3,4,5]
```

Any idea on what is going on here?

**Update:**
upon running following in IronPython Console for windows

```
>>>import sys
>>>sys.version
'2.7.1 <IronPython 2.7.1 <2.7.0.40) on .NET 4.0.30319.239)'
```

Same behavior inside PyScripter and VSTS for Python
The main window produces no output(Any idea? Running PyScripter 2.4.3) and the interpreter below produced

```
'3.2.2 (default, sep 4 2011, 09:51:08) [....]'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IronPython is still at 2.x, in which `print` is a statement and `range()` returns a list. Both of these [changed with 3.x](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.3/whatsnew/3.0.html).

Answer (score 1):

These seem like Python 2 to 3 differences. Check to ensure that each is running the same version. print is a function in 3 and requires parentheses. range becomes an iterator and so won't display output unless enclosed in a type function e.g. list(_).

Answer (score 1):

Each console is using a different version of Python.  Run this in each of your consoles:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.version
```